# 21" monitor recommendation

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for a 21" (or larger) monitor to use with my work laptop when working from home. I work with excel, word and some statistics packages (like STATA or SAS) mostly. I'm not a gamer so won't use it for that (Football Manager is the only thing I play these days and that's a glorified spreadsheet). Ideally I'd get something for around the £100 mark, but I don't know whether that's realistic? Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could not find something at a local thrift shop that would work nicely. I have noticed that an e-commerce site I use here in the US for electronics seems to have monitors of 27" or smaller on sale regularly for US$125 or less with 21" usually below US$90.

Comment: I recent bought 2 x 22" (1680 x 1050) monitors on a well know auction site for £25 each which is typical, and you can get a new 21.5" (1920 x 1080) for £90-£100. There is not a lot between them all, so for a specific recommendation, you'll need to provide more detail as to what your needs are.... cont'd..

Comment: ...cont'd... what connection type does your laptop support? VGA/DVI/DisplayPort/HDMI? What resolution do you need? What other features are important? Power consumption? Contrast/brightness? Brand? Warranty period?

Comment: In all honesty, there are so many decent, cheap alternatives out there, with few stand-out performers, that you are unlikely to get much from this posting, unless you come up with a very specific/uncommon requirement

Comment: Thanks, I don't really have any more detailed requirements. Still, helpful to know that I can pretty much buy anything and it'll be ok.

Comment: If you want to go super-fancy, my recent research for about the same size has found the Dell P2217H to be about as top-of-the-line as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Monitors are pretty standardized for plug-and-play use.  Just make sure that the resolution is compatible with your computer (i.e. not too low and not too high).  I would recommend buying one used, to save some money, but make sure that the seller includes a money-back guarantee and preferably has some kind of certification for refurbishment (i.e. don't buy it at a yardsale unless you trust the seller).  Well-established sellers such as Amazon.com, BestBuy.com, Walmart.com, and Staples.com are usually trustworthy to purchase refurbished monitors from.  If possible, I would recommend a clicks-to-bricks store so you can easily return it in person at a local store if there are any problems (shipping a monitor back might be difficult I think).

I actually just bought a nice 22-inch 1680*1050 monitor yesterday at my local computer shop for an amazing US$24.50.  They had smaller monitors selling for as low as US$7.00!  They are a Microsoft-certified refurbisher and all the monitors come with a 90-day guarantee.  https://www.techreup.com/

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include a specific hardware recommendation please. This boils down to "buy used from one of these stores", which isn't really helpful. Please check out our [Answer Quality Guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/59/60) if you have any questions.

Comment: My point was that you shouldn't need a specific recommendation for a generic (flatscreen) monitor.  It's plug-and-play.  In my experience when it comes to generic used hardware, the trustworthiness of the seller is more important than what is being sold (the monitor I bought the day before yesterday is a Gateway, who doesn't even exist any more).  My recommendation is to check local shops in the area for used monitors before shopping online.